# Inferring a Typescript generic from a static property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a library where the user may define subclasses of the abstract class `State`. Any subclass of `State` will "rely" (within the logic of the library) on a number of classes inherited from the abstract class `Component`. These dependencies must be declared in the code statically so my library can analyze them up-front. I'd like to also typecheck the methods of the `State`-inherited user classes based on the dependencies they define. Here is an example:

```
class ComponentA extends Component {}
class ComponentB extends Component {}

class ExampleState extends State {
  static dependencies = [ComponentA, ComponentB] as const;

  // this method should correctly type the tuple provided to this
  // user-defined method as containing an instance of ComponentA
  // in position 0 and an instance of ComponentB in position 1, ordered as
  // provided in the static dependencies property.
  initialize(components) {
    const [a, b] = components;
    console.assert(a instanceof ComponentA); // true
  }
}
```

Specifically, I would like to avoid forcing the user to also pass a generic to `State` like `State<[typeof ComponentA, typeof ComponentB]>` which would be both verbose and redundant. However, I cannot rely *only* on the generic instead, because I need the dependency information at runtime.

Are there any options for defining this in TypeScript? Or are statics simply too divorced from instances to be able to share this type information? Is there another pattern (perhaps besides classes) which would be able to accomplish the right developer ergonomics for this usage?

### Update

After a lot of experimentation, I have discovered at least one possible usage which maintains ergonomics (type hints on the `initialize` method according to the specified dependencies) without requiring redundancy in the code:

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbADvAdgUzQF2gbwF8BYAKAEscMAnAMzGAziVUxwBUBPZDAHlmgwAPbFgAmMBCnRZsAPnyloS6JgDuACgCUALjgBuUsRIB6AFSnoAQWjB0ANyxksDaBRG16jbPGhUM2KicHJilWXFEMbjQItGAnGAAjDmhObmhTY1I3ajoXSRYZAHF-dz5maRwYIRFoiXKw1N4wNA5ZAG0AXXk8RWUAc38+AWExOtCZCDaABi71Rt1YHThhmvEQgvYuXgoaamgASXkAfgPdTAcqAxIjLMoPFwBlbDARMvGcABFIqpHa9YrsI0eM1Wp1oABeaCdbq9MymXrpOBgEAgDCiaCqAAWWGgYGgTxejDIMBoZCoEFwkAg8DihPRqjI2ExuLQ0AAojhGckmS9oIgXsBsTBGWMNtgERYIlEYnEMBAAHQpTHE6AQTHwACuIHRfgg-mgTMYBJEuOAtioogofQNPhB0AidC12BgzXRtjQpL6Gr8EpZyWkAFpsGREES0IyyMjoMgqPBuFRg3LoDRY4h-mF7S8wPKJZkSEoKBHkWQAF4YdQImz1CYLas4YrYUr5AFfZAQWQAGl6SwACqnibw7PAyKJ5AAfaBDkeGUikGga2LB9B8sAAawwxt4rZ+q1FAKBIPasylYmc8V0247queIlgfhe8Coui0EPkm5429kmgU+eUxmMVZauiGp6q4KCxg4oY4FeI4YMiIDJMA94mni2BbAamK8tUozXoSd5wd4VA2riojogARBSLxkMAZH2pEp6xPEOa-ko6iUbeyGPriLotJo8ontEZ5JpCAkyvEVzKL4-jeqy7EYPhD6XDOJCkP+7KCGAKCotAIFgAMGKMsy1KhumEykKAVKmTg1jYX8zYZj0LGTsiGqMJCADMVxGBZUBWdgABCKw4fZMg-pJohZhC0AAOQ0PA8DRV5s4kO6FLqZpyDaZC-Lrpu6htCF1lXoVAUdFeL7gjCTlqaA8AQN6jB2GAgRgAkqIwNifimrghqqppjCQDY4C+RQlGxI1zWRm1cqVqiuC6pqVAMLoFKBGg1oTmgWogFFW0olclZqUyKp+NgMnQPACQAFYYMAuCYTAaFpMqlQAISVqd52OZJkkLd6DBdk5kmFsGxZluotjvM637fT9cN-UtblVlDCoDNg6glf5fERc80AANTI2KqP+BjdbYJYfFNSArkSXD0BGJJBBeZoQA)

However, the usage is still a little awkward. The user must supply a function to create their pseudo-class object, and utilize a closure to store "instance properties" which they normally would simply attach to their subclass.

I'm still interested to see if someone can come up with a more streamlined solution, but if not I'll self-answer with at least this, which works.

### Update 2: More details on my goal

I'm working on a framework library for creating web games which is inspired by / extending the ECS pattern for game development. The piece I want to add to ECS is a way for framework users or complementary library authors to define declarative state management based on certain combinations of Components being attached to any particular Entity.

As a user writing a game with the framework, I want to enable a pattern like "If any Entity has the Components `[Image, Position, Color]` attached to it at any point in the game's lifecycle, a `Sprite` "State" object should be constructed by the framework which derives its data from those Components."

To accomplish this, the user will provide State definitions to the framework which implement an `initialize`/`destroy` interface. These State definitions will be responsible for providing the imperative logic to enable declarative usage in the game's logic code.

Here's a sketch of usage I'd ideally want to enable, using a hypothetical `SomeSpriteThing` resource analogous to something from PixiJS or ThreeJS, for example:

```
class SpriteState extends State {
  static dependencies = [Image, Position, Color] as const;

  private sprite = new SomeSpriteThing();

  initialize([image, position, color]) {
    this.sprite.src = image.src;
    this.sprite.x = position.x;
    this.sprite.y = position.y;
    this.sprite.tint = color.value;
    this.sprite.load();
  }

  destroy() {
    this.sprite.unload();
  }
}
```

A library user would provide such State classes to the framework, and whenever an Entity is assigned `[Image, Position, Color]` components together, a `SpriteState` will be generated by the framework and made available to game logic code.

However, in the ideal usage above, `initialize` would have no way of inferring the typings of the provided tuple from the `dependencies` static.

As a Typescript-focused library, I want the code which users write to be thoroughly typechecked without excessive effort on their part in specifying redundant typings. That's why I'd like to avoid forcing the user to provide the same list of dependency types to a generic parameter in the `State` superclass - not only is it inconvenient, but there is no way to enforce that the `dependencies` and the generic remain in sync, as one is only visible to code and the other to typechecking.

I recognize this is not a pattern I've seen before and is possibly quite over-engineered. Perhaps that's all there is to it. But I was curious if there was some possible way of approaching this with type-safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any options for defining this in TypeScript? Or are statics simply too divorced from instances to be able to share this type information?

When you create a class `ExampleState` you also create a type `ExampleState` which describes an *instance* of that class.  The static properties do **not** apply to the `ExampleState` since they are not instance properties.  Each class also has a second type, `typeof ExampleState` or `new () => ExampleState`, which describes the *constructor* of the class.  This is where the static properties are defined.  ([relevant docs section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions))

> Is there another pattern (perhaps besides classes) which would be able to accomplish the right developer ergonomics for this usage?

My recommendation is to use some sort of higher-order function to create your classes.  It's hard for me to get this exactly right because I don't fully understand the use case, but this should point you in the right direction at least.

This interface describes the *constructor* that we want.  It can be instantiated to create a `State<Deps>` and it also has a property `dependencies` of type `Deps`.

```
interface StateCreator<Deps extends ComponentType<any>[]> {
    new (): State<Deps>;
    dependencies: Deps;
}
```

This function takes your dependencies and returns an anonymous class which has those dependencies as static properties.

```
function makeState<Deps extends ComponentType<any>[]>(dependencies: Deps): StateCreator<Deps> {
    return class extends State<Deps> {
        static dependencies: Deps = dependencies;

        initialize(components: Deps) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit lost on what your intention is with `initialize`.  Why would we provide `Deps` as an argument if `Deps` is already known from the static properties?  Did you mean for this to take *instances* of `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`?

Comment: I apologize, in my edits to reduce my code example to the essentials, I did indeed accidentally mix up component instances vs. constructors. `initialize` receives instances of the components whose constructors are supplied as dependencies. I will update the question.

My desired usage as a library is to be able to actually define the resulting class (which inherits from State), specifying the Component constructors it depends on statically, and getting typechecking on their instances as they are passed to `initialize`, which the user defines.

Comment: To clarify, I think the factory approach is a good one (I have a similar idea in my update on the question). But one of my goals is to have TS automatically suggest and enforce typing for the `initialize` method _as the user defines it_. The library is providing tools to help the user define State subclasses which are type-safe according to their `dependencies`, but the user defines the class in the end.

In English, the intent is like: "I want to define a kind of State which depends on these Components and implements this `initialize` for a set of instances of those components."

Comment: I think I'm not quite "getting" this.  My general inclination is for composition over inheritance.  I'm not sure what functionality we are inheriting from `State` and whether we can get use a compositional pattern to combine that functionality with the `initialize` that we want to define.

Comment: I've probably either failed to provide enough context, or my goal is too over-engineered. Nevertheless, I've added more detail about the specifics of what I'm trying to build to the question if you're interested. I'm thinking that my desired usage pattern is probably not possible with TS... I appreciate you engaging with the question anyway. If what I've added is clear and the answer is "you can't do that" you're welcome to add that to your answer and I'll accept it, given that your other suggestions have been helpful for reframing the problem already.

Comment: Honestly, after reading over this again, I do think I'm overthinking it. This is a case where the user already knows exactly what the provided data to `initialize` will be, since they've specified it themselves in `dependencies`. This is probably a case where providing automatic typechecking is past the point of diminishing returns...

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `initialize` instead of a `constructor`?

Comment: So I played with this for a while because I actually really like thinking about design.  This code still has issues, but is it moving in the right direction? https://tsplay.dev/GmZl9w

Comment: I went with `initialize` because the resulting State objects would be pooled to reduce garbage collection.

I see the idea you're exploring with your code example! I was focused on State being able to initialize itself, but your design of a separate Factory is definitely a simpler approach. Really nicely done!

As for the details like `as const`, I actually omitted a proxy object used to retrieve component dependencies for brevity, so this is a non-issue (in my framework getting a Component would be `dependencies.get(Color)`, for example, since order does not matter).

Comment: I accepted the answer, although perhaps adding the link to your sandbox would round it out to point anyone else interested in the right direction.